# Does anyone have a bash command line example for updating a job status in Tidal Scheduler?

Tags: tidal-scheduler

I'm trying to use the tidal API to update some work flows which currently aren't available in the scheduler itself.

I use the below to rerun job number 12345

```
wget --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies=/mypath/to/tidal-cookies.txt -qO- "http://tidal.myhost.com/api/tes-6.3-prod/JobRun.rerun/12345"
```

But if I wanted to assign the status as Completed Normally or any other status I'm not sure how that is supported

```
 wget --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies=/mypath/to/tidal-cookies.txt -qO- "https://tidal.myhost.com/api/tes-6.3-prod/JobRun.assignStatus<id>12345</id><status>'Completed%20Normally'</status>"
```

Just errors out, and trying with an xml file

```
 wget --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies=/mypath/to/tidal-cookies.txt "http://tidal.myhost.com/api/tes-6.3-prod/post" --post-file=/tmp/status.xml


cat /tmp/status.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <entry xmlns='http://purl.org/atom/ns#'>
  <tes:JobRun.assignStatus xmlns:tes='http://tidal.myhost.com/client/tesservlet'>
   <id>123456</id>
   <status>66</status>
   </tes:JobRun.assignStatus>
 </entry>
```

Gives an error

```
Length: unspecified [application/atom+xml]
Saving to: ‘post.4’

    [ <=>                                                                                                                                                                                                ] 3,890       --.-K/s   in 0s

2023-08-09 05:24:01 (121 MB/s) - ‘post.4’ saved [3890]
```

Exception processing request.TES2023-08-09T05:24:01.525-04:001javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

- with linked exception:
  [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]
  at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
  at com.tidalsoft.framework.xml.XmlSerializer.deserialize(XmlSerializer.java:285)
  at com.tidalsoft.framework.atom.AtomSerializer.deserialize(AtomSerializer.java:120)
  at com.tidalsoft.webclient.tes.dsp.DataSourceProviderImpl$ProcessRequest.initialize(DataSourceProviderImpl.java:3290)
  at com.tidalsoft.framework.execute.Execution.execute(Execution.java:25)
  at com.tidalsoft.framework.execute.Execution.execute(Execution.java:17)

```
I tried the above 2 approaches with no luck
```